# Alfresco - documents list on workflow details page

Tags: alfresco

I would like to know how the document list is rendered on workflow details page in Alfresco Share. I mean which components (Java class, Java script, FTL, XML) are responsible to add document list on in workflow-details page.

I searched through the code and found workflow-form.get.html.ftl, however it takes care of all other data to be rendered on this page except document list. Its getting populated dynamically it seems but I don't understand how.

Thanks,
Hemant

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source on that page you'll find a clue:

```
<label for="page_x002e_data-form_x002e_task-edit_x0023_default_assoc_packageItems-cntrl">Items:</label>
```

If you go grep for "packageItems" you'll soon find that a form control called packageitems.ftl:

```
target/share-war/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/site-webscripts/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/workflow/packageitems.ftl
```

If you go look at that form control it should give you a good starting point in understanding how it works.

Answer (score 0):

It was always confusing for me as well.For defining the workflow details field, there is a separate form for it.

For each workflow there is start task which we are defining in workflow model.for this start task we need to define workflow details form as well.

Below is one of the example where for bpm:startTask workflow-details form is defined.

```
   <config evaluator="task-type" condition="bpm:startTask">
  <forms>
     **<form id="workflow-details">
        <field-visibility>
           <show id="bpm:sendEMailNotifications" />
           <show id="packageItems" />
        </field-visibility>
        <appearance>
           <set id="" appearance="title" label-id="workflow.set.workflow.more_info" />
           <set id="items" appearance="title" label-id="workflow.set.items" />
           <field id="packageItems" set="items" />
        </appearance>
     </form>**

     <form>
        <field-visibility>
           <show id="message" />
           <show id="taskOwner" />
           <show id="bpm:workflowPriority" />
           <show id="bpm:workflowDueDate" />
           <show id="bpm:taskId" />
           <show id="bpm:status" />
           <show id="packageItems" />
           <show id="bpm:sendEMailNotifications" />
        </field-visibility>
        <appearance>
           <set id="" appearance="title" label-id="workflow.set.task.info" />
           <set id="info" appearance="" template="/org/alfresco/components/form/3-column-set.ftl" />
           <set id="progress" appearance="title" label-id="workflow.set.task.progress" />
           <set id="items" appearance="title" label-id="workflow.set.items" />
           <set id="other" appearance="title" label-id="workflow.set.other" />

           <field id="message">
              <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/info.ftl" />
           </field>
           <field id="taskOwner" set="info" />
           <field id="bpm:taskId" set="info">
              <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/info.ftl" />
           </field>
           <field id="bpm:workflowPriority" label-id="workflow.field.priority" set="info" read-only="true">
              <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/workflow/priority.ftl" />
           </field>
           <field id="bpm:workflowDueDate" set="info" label-id="workflow.field.due">
              <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/info.ftl" />
           </field>
           <field id="bpm:status" set="progress" />
           <field id="bpm:sendEMailNotifications" set="other" />
           <field id="packageItems" set="items" />
        </appearance>
     </form>
  </forms>
```

If you would like to change anything in document list rendering you can extend packageitems.ftl which is suggested by Jeff.